# I need a regex which accepts patterns like “(abc OR (def AND dshd))..etc

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

Example:
I need a regex pattern which accepts patterns in the following combination

1. String should accept both with braces and without braces, first word of every string should start either with NOT or without NOT.
2. Every word in the sentence should be followed by AND/OR.
3. Eg: “(NOT cbe AND (man OR hen))

Comment: what is your regular expression so far?

Comment: Since you are trying to handle nested structures regex is not best tool. You are most likely looking for parser. Maybe try to create one with ANTLR.

Comment: @Pshemo Wish I could upvote your comment more than once.  I have also gotten good mileage from a tool called [Javaluator](http://javaluator.sourceforge.net/en/home/).

Comment: Now you have two problems.  Obligatory reference: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/18157

Comment: (((?:[(]* ?[a-z][a-z]+ ?[)]*)|[(]* ?(NOT) (?:[(]* ?[a-z][a-z]+ ?[)]*) ?[)]*)( (AND|OR) ((?:[(]* ?[a-z][a-z]+ ?[)]*)|[(]* ?(NOT) (?:[(]* ?[a-z][a-z]+ ?[)]*) ?[)]*))*)  this is my current regex @aimee

Answer (score 0):

Question isn't clear, but based on information provided:
/(NOT |)([A-Z-a-z])\w+ (AND|OR) (([A-Z-a-z])\w+ (AND|OR) ([A-Z-a-z])\w+)/g

works fine for below cases:
(NOT cbe AND (man OR hen))
(cbe AND (man OR hen))
NOT cbe AND (man OR hen)

Here is the link: http://regexr.com/3eoik

Comment: I believe in Java regex a / (slash) matches itself, so I don’t understand why you begin with it. I played a bit around with your link, and I think it behaves funnily in some situations. It finds no match in “(NOT cbe AND man OR hen)”. Neither in “(NOT c AND (man OR hen))”.